# Get column and row number for named range

Tags: excel, named-ranges, vba

I am having a problem referencing a column next to a named range (the NamedRange is only 1 column wide).  I have used the following code to insert a column:

`.sheets("sheet1").Range("NamedRange:NamedRange").EntireColumn.Insert`

This works but inserts the column before the `NamedRange`. It doesn't matter if I add

`shift:=xlToRight` or `shift:=xlToLeft`

It ignores me and inserts the column to the left.

A couple of questions:

1. How can I insert a column to the right of the NamedRange?
2. How can I reference row 1 of the new column to put a header to my new column?  In other words, how do I find the address of the new column cell(row1,column???)? And how can I extract the new column address of the NamedRange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I insert a column to the right of the NamedRange?

Use .Offset to achieve what you want.

```
Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("NamedRange").offset(,1).EntireColumn.Insert
```

> how can I reference row 1 of the new column to put a header to my new column?

Work with the Range Object

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rngNm As Range, NewRng As Range

    Set rngNm = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("NamedRange")

    rngNm.Offset(, 1).EntireColumn.Insert

    Set NewRng = rngNm.Offset(, 1)

    Debug.Print NewRng.Address '<~~ New Columsn Address
    Debug.Print NewRng.Cells(1,1).Address '<~~ 1st Cell in the range
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.  The first line works great.    The sub has a problem.  At   set  rngNm = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("NamedRange")  I get a '1004 error, Application-definded or object-defined error'.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you replace the `NamedRange` with the actual named range?